# Swift: Programmatically changing my UISegmentedControl's Items

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to change the items in my UISegmentedControl based off of another selection. I do not want to change the number of items, but simply the item labels, as well as the 'hidden' variable of the UISegmentedControl.

Here is my code to get the UISegmentedControl:

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewPicker: UISegmentedControl!
```

and here is the code to change it:

```
viewPicker = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Description", "Location"])
```

However, this doesn't work and sometimes sets viewPicker to nil, giving an error. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are declaring your variable as "weak", it will get deallocated as soon as you assign it. But you should not do it anyway, because it is @IBOutlet -> you should connect it through interface builder.

As for changing the title, instead of just creating new SC, use

```
self.viewPicker.setTitle("", forSegmentAtIndex: index)
```

And to hide / show segmented control,

```
self.viewPicker.hidden = true / false
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

The UISegmentControl has a method that lets you change the labels individually called: 
`setTitle(_:forSegmentAtIndex:)`. So you just use it on your segmented control like so:

```
self.viewPicker.setTitle("Description", forSegmentAtIndex:0)
self.viewPicker.setTitle("Location", forSegmentAtIndex:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3.0 use:

```
 self.viewPicker.setTitle("Description", forSegmentAt: 0)
 self.viewPicker.setTitle("Location", forSegmentAt: 1)
```